# How to get write permissions in twitter ios7

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, twitter

In twitter app whenever i am update read and write permissions it is showing error "You must add your mobile phone to your Twitter profile before granting your application write capabilities" and when i am entering my mobile number it is showing this error "Sorry, we don't have a connection to your carrier yet!.Don't worry, we're on it and will let you know once things are set up. In the meantime, use one of our long codes". I am working on iOS simulator.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a smartphone, that is. Just log on to the twitter site using your phone and use the mobile site. Click the settings tab and add your phone number (with the country code). You will immediately receive the confirmation link as well as key. Confirm it online and you are all set!